# CollectionView cell is selected when swiped on

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collectionView showing cells. When I drag/touch/slide my finger on an item, if the touch ends on the item, the cell is selected (segues to the details screen).

Is there any way to limit cell selection (`didSelectItemAt indexPath`) to a simple tap? i.e it shouldn't select the cell if finger is dragged on an item and the touch ends on it.

Is this the default behavior?

I feel like it might be the cause of a cryptic issue with my custom navigation.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Don't implement `didSelectItemAt` at all and add `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the cell instead

Answer (score 0):

Do add Following in your cellForItem

```
 let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(cellTapped(tapGestureRecognizer:)))
    tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
cell.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

And add following function

```
@IBAction func cellTapped(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
//Do your required work.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UITapGestureRecognizer`, cause it will only respond on Tap gesture:

```
@objc func tapAction(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    // TODO: - Action you need
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: <CellReuseId>, for: indexPath) 
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapAction(_:)))
    cell.contentView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    return cell
}
```

> But in  this way `didSelectItemAt` will not work.